# How to add children to a specific to several grids

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Project, Main window contains several grids. 
After creating Textboxes and -blocks in a loop I add them to a grid using:

```
grid1.Children.Add(textbox1);
grid2.Children.Add(textbox2);
...
grid20.Children.Add(textbox20);
```

Is it somehow possible to replace this piece of code with a loop too?

Comment: I think there are various ways depends on your UI design. How is ListBox or DataGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many of these grid/textboxes it might be wiser to wrap them in another control as Yaho Cho suggested in his comment..

I might be stating the obvious, but if you place the grids and textboxes in a list (i.e. create them in code and add them to the container in code) you can loop them.

```
List<TextBox> tl = new List<TextBox>(){ ... };
List<Grid> gl = new List<Grid>(){ ... }
for (i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        gl[i].Children.Add(tl[i]);
        container.Children.Add(gl[i]);
    }
```